# Why does my server hostname appear in SMTP email headers sent from another domain?

Tags: email, smtp, smtp-headers

I have seen some similar questions here however i am still to find a proper fix to this issue.

The issues are as follow:

I am trying to send  emails from this `email@domain2.com` email address I  created, via SMTP using the dedicated IP address that domain is assigned  with.
I made the necessary change in exim configurator to use the accounts dedicated IP but the hostname is still the one of my main domain.

When I check the sent emails, and click “*Show Original*” I still  see the hostname of my main domain I have the VPS installed on   (`server1.maindomain.com`) instead of `mail.domain2.com`

This is the exact message I get:

> Received: from 5-12-190-158.residential.rdsnet.ro
>   ([5.12.190.158]:63029  helo=[127.0.0.1]) by server1.maindomain.com
>   with esmtpa (Exim 4.87)  (envelope-from ) id 
>   1cK2HF-0000kd-Dh for blahblah@gmail.com; Thu, 22 Dec 2016 07:15:17 
>   -0500

My question is, how can I change that so that only the active hostname I’m using will show (`mail.domain2.com`)?

Thank you and awaiting your reply

Comment: What is reverse DNS for your IP set to?

Answer (score 1):

*Received* header form a list of all the servers/computers through which the message traveled in order to reach you.

The received lines are best read from bottom to top. That is, the first "*Received*:" line is your own system or mail server. The last "*Received*:" line is where the mail originated. Each mail system has their own style of "*Received*:" line. A "*Received*:" line typically identifies the machine that received the mail and the machine from which the mail was received.

More info about it you can found in [RFC 822: section 4.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-4.3), and [RFC 1123: section 5.2.8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#section-5.2.8)

If you wish to remove these headers(not a good idea), you should add option `headers_remove = Received` to your exim's [router configuration](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-generic_options_for_routers.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however that does not answer my question yet. I know how to remove those headers and what they mean, my question was if i can show the domain i'm using to send email instead of the hostname of the main domain vps is hosted on...

Answer (score 0):

The name other internet hosts will find for you IP address is the reverse DNS name associated with that address.  You can check the reverse DNS name with e.g. `dig -x 5.12.190.158`.  Setting the reverse DNS name has to be done by whoever controls the IP range, which is usually the ISP that assigned that address to you.  How to request that they change the name varies; it may not be possible (especially for residential connections), but I'd expect it to be available from most VPS providers.